# Cant reliably receive POST json data in PHP from some sources

Tags: php, api, post

I am trying to work with an API that is sending data to my server in json format through a POST command.

I am using

```
<?PHP 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *');
header('HTTP/1.1 201 Accepted');

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

if(!empty($data)){
    echo "Not Empty";
} else {
    echo "Is Empty";
}
echo ': '.$data;

?>
```

For testing:

When I use **reqbin.com** I get a successful response, but no data is returned

When I use **apitester.com** everything works as expected, the json is echoed property.

What could be causing one service to work, and one not to work, when both are POSTing the same json file to my server.

***I know I will need to use json_decode eventually to work with the data, but I'm just trying to test receiving the data... any data at this point.

Response from reqbin:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Accepted
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 04:36:52 GMT
Server: Apache
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Is Empty:
```

Respons from apitester:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Accepted
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 04:38:48 GMT
Server: Apache
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Not Empty: {
    "PublicKey":"12121212121212121212121212121212",
    "TimeStamp":"MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS",
    "TokenKey":"34343434343434343434343434343434",
    "Action":"AUTHORIZE",
    "SecureURL":"https://merchant-store.3dcartstores.com",
}
```

---

Update:

I have noticed that reqbin uses CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER set to true for their request. Could my server be rejecting that?

Comment: Maybe try  a regular, real HTTP client like `curl` instead of an online service? Might also give you more detailed output if something is wrong.

Comment: I am using an online service to test because the API I will be interacting with is also an online service. My question is specifically about these online services... why one would work, and one would not work.

When I use curl from my command prompt it works as expected.

Comment: If you want to make it work with these websites, you should get the full requests + responses from them and post them in your question.

Comment: Updated question with the response received using each service.

Comment: The difference between the two will be in the request they are sending, but the responses are also helpful!